# Update an object using Tastypie Django

Tags: django, api, tastypie

I'm trying to update an object using Tastypie Api in Django but I can't find any way to do it...

I would like to send an URL like /api/vote/pk=3, which would update the object with pk=3 and increment the vote number field... Is it possible to do it easily ?

Thanks by advance...

I just tried to create a Ressource like this : but it doesn't work even if i don't do any process. It requires to define obj_get_list etc...

```
class IphoneVoteRessource(Resource): 
    id = fields.IntegerField(attribute='id') 
    name = fields.CharField(attribute='name') 

class Meta: 
    resource_name = 'poi_vote' 
    object_class = Row 

def obj_update(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs): 
    # update an existing row 
    pk = int(kwargs['pk']) 
    return bundle `
```

I already used a lot of times Tastypie to get data, but never to update one object..

Comment: I just tried to create a Ressource like this : but it doesn't work even if i don't do any process. It requires to define obj_get_list etc...

`
class IphoneVoteRessource(Resource):

    id = fields.IntegerField(attribute='id')
    name = fields.CharField(attribute='name')

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'poi_vote'
        object_class = Row

    def obj_update(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
        # update an existing row
        pk = int(kwargs['pk'])
        return bundle
`

I already used a lot of times Tastypie to get data, but never to update one object...

Answer (score 0):

I have finally used a ModelResource,if somebody wants an example which works :

```
class VoteResourceAnonymous(ModelResource):

class Meta:
    queryset = VoteAnonymous.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'vote_object'
    # need to send 'vote_value' and 'object_id'
    excludes = ['created_at', 'content_type', 'content_object', 'user_agent', 'ip_address']
    allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']
    always_return_data = True

def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):

    vote_value = bundle.data['vote_value']
    object_id = bundle.data['object_id']

    tmp_poi = PointOfInterestActivity.objects.get(id=object_id)
    content_type_object = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(tmp_poi)

    bundle.obj = VoteAnonymous(vote_value=vote_value,
                               object_id=object_id,
                               user_agent="",
                               ip_address="",
                               content_type=content_type_object,
                               )

    bundle.obj.save()

    if vote_value > 0:
        bundle.data['new_nb_votes'] = tmp_poi.nb_votes + 1
    else:
        bundle.data['new_nb_votes'] = tmp_poi.nb_votes - 1

    return bundle
```